# App Crashes on Startup with iOS 5 - Cannot Reproduce

Tags: ios, ios5, crash, nsuserdefaults, startup

Our iOS app is crashing on startup for a small percentage of our users.

1. We cannot reproduce this crash on any of multiple test devices, either when connected to Xcode, or not connected
2. The crash only happens on iOS 5, but happens on iPod, iPhone, and iPad
3. The crash is a watchdog timeout on startup
4. Only a few of our users experience the crash
5. The app only crashes when the users are upgrading
6. The crash stops happening if the user deletes, then reinstalls the app
7. Turning the device off and on again does not help
8. The only XIB used in the project is a basically empty XIB for the main window

We would surely appreciate hearing if anyone has any ideas where this crash could be coming from. We've been trying to track it down unsuccessfully for a month.

Thanks so much!

Here's our application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor myBackgroundColor]];

    gRootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadGame) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    return YES;

}
```

Here's the symbolicated crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: 8AC99711-0817-4A93-AEFB-82E24FFE3291
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         myapp [92]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/B90DCE6D-F392-493E-8BC8-7FE0A64D80B0/myapp.app/myapp
Identifier:      myapp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-04-04 21:52:17.108 -0500
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1 (9B176)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.mycompany.myapp failed to launch in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 20.130 (user 20.130, system 0.000), 100% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 14.747, 73% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x34fe7930 CFBasicHashFindBucket + 2012
1   CoreFoundation                  0x34fe713e CFDictionaryGetValue + 110
2   CoreFoundation                  0x35054722 __CFBinaryPlistCreateObject2 + 38
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35055514 __CFBinaryPlistCreateObject2 + 3608
4   CoreFoundation                  0x35055514 __CFBinaryPlistCreateObject2 + 3608
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3505574e __CFTryParseBinaryPlist + 158
6   CoreFoundation                  0x34ffe9a0 _CFPropertyListCreateWithData + 80
7   CoreFoundation                  0x350175da CFPropertyListCreateWithStream + 430
8   CoreFoundation                  0x350173c0 CFPropertyListCreateFromStream + 56
9   CoreFoundation                  0x350170f0 -[CFXPreferencesPropertyListSourceSynchronizer createPlistFromDisk] + 128
10  CoreFoundation                  0x35007532 -[CFXPreferencesPropertyListSourceSynchronizer synchronizeAlreadyFlocked] + 242
11  CoreFoundation                  0x35007436 -[CFXPreferencesPropertyListSourceSynchronizer synchronize] + 14
12  CoreFoundation                  0x35016b34 -[CFXPreferencesPropertyListSource synchronize] + 104
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3509050e __CFXPreferencesGetSourceForTriplet + 454
14  CoreFoundation                  0x35090238 __CFXPreferencesGetSearchListForBundleID + 164
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3509192e ___CFXPreferencesCopyAppValue_block_invoke_0 + 6
16  CoreFoundation                  0x34fe8b24 CFPreferencesCopyAppValue + 276
17  Foundation                      0x30ed341c -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) initWithUser:] + 1356
18  Foundation                      0x30eb28f8 +[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) standardUserDefaults] + 100
19  UIKit                           0x320f015e _InitMagnificationFilter + 26
20  libsystem_c.dylib               0x36d4b7ce pthread_once + 70
21  UIKit                           0x320dbbcc -[UIView _createLayerWithFrame:] + 424
22  UIKit                           0x320db874 UIViewCommonInitWithFrame + 348
23  UIKit                           0x320db6dc -[UIView initWithFrame:] + 92
24  UIKit                           0x320effaa -[UIStatusBar initWithFrame:showForegroundView:] + 46
25  UIKit                           0x320eff70 -[UIStatusBar initWithFrame:] + 32
26  UIKit                           0x320efdc6 -[UIApplication _createStatusBarWithRequestedStyle:orientation:hidden:] + 78
27  UIKit                           0x320ef876 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 138
28  UIKit                           0x320bdc64 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1004
29  UIKit                           0x320bd708 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 48
30  UIKit                           0x320bd0dc _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5820
31  GraphicsServices                0x362f2224 PurpleEventCallback + 876
32  CoreFoundation                  0x3507351c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
33  CoreFoundation                  0x350734be __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
34  CoreFoundation                  0x3507230c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364
35  CoreFoundation                  0x34ff549e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
36  CoreFoundation                  0x34ff5366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
37  UIKit                           0x320eea0c -[UIApplication _run] + 544
38  UIKit                           0x320ebe76 UIApplicationMain + 1074
39  myapp                               0x00005800 main (main.m:62)
40  myapp                               0x00002404 0x1000 + 5124

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34e833a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x310d0ea4 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x310d0bc2 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34e83004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34e831fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x350733ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35072124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34ff549e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x34ff5366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x36e780f0 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36d5072e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36d505e8 thread_start + 0

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x1afff +myapp armv7  <31178538f2203d4095608727afa603d5> /var/mobile/Applications/B90DCE6D-F392-493E-8BC8-7FE0A64D80B0/myapp.app/myapp
0x2fe5a000 - 0x2fe7bfff  dyld armv7  <4a817f3e0def30d5ae2032157d889c1d> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3030e000 - 0x30312fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x30313000 - 0x30313fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x30373000 - 0x308b7fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x308b8000 - 0x30937fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3095f000 - 0x30a37fff  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x30a4e000 - 0x30a55fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x30a56000 - 0x30aa7fff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x30b39000 - 0x30b39fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x30b3a000 - 0x30baafff  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x30be0000 - 0x30c1cfff  iCalendar armv7  <f2836083051132d3aa40ad82d7f73aea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x30c1d000 - 0x30c28fff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x30c29000 - 0x30c29fff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x30c4d000 - 0x30c96fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x30c97000 - 0x30c9afff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x30c9b000 - 0x30d21fff  CoreMotion armv7  <6a9355d5a8e238b5b8f193605d509e15> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x30d5b000 - 0x30d5cfff  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x30d6f000 - 0x30daffff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x30db0000 - 0x30db1fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x30dca000 - 0x30de9fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x30dea000 - 0x30e22fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x30ea9000 - 0x30eb0fff  StoreKit armv7  <1bc0c05f99a8309d90476b42263e3487> /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit
0x30eb1000 - 0x3102ffff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x3103b000 - 0x3103cfff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x3103d000 - 0x31052fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x31053000 - 0x31078fff  OpenCL armv7  <ec915bfc3f7633dda61b5fc87459119b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x310bd000 - 0x310c3fff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x310c4000 - 0x310dafff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x310db000 - 0x310e5fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x310ec000 - 0x310f1fff  ApplePushService armv7  <f424c0340de637c08bbeb4f3bd8c6eaf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x31131000 - 0x31142fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x31143000 - 0x31143fff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x31149000 - 0x31186fff  FTServices armv7  <28ed78e01a77388cb4c0f2f6ec33482c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x311a6000 - 0x3121afff  MediaControlSender armv7  <87315c54b2293ab589950341ff91b45d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x3121b000 - 0x31257fff  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x313f2000 - 0x31416fff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x3141a000 - 0x3144efff  MIME armv7  <d30292ea8f7e360fa5f5d5b1b62b602d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x31476000 - 0x3147afff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x31485000 - 0x3152bfff  AddressBookUI armv7  <da424fecc66e3628ab03378ae80b38fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x31550000 - 0x3158efff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x315f9000 - 0x315fafff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x316f8000 - 0x316fffff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <0703f561f9a038b6850d6e93bba7e5f4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x31700000 - 0x31701fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x31767000 - 0x317b1fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x317e4000 - 0x31841fff  StoreServices armv7  <628fbbc73ed93730962c53bfbfde6794> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x31a2d000 - 0x31b72fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x31b98000 - 0x31ba7fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x31ba8000 - 0x31c5efff  AVFoundation armv7  <35cb7a0eb1dc3554a777c1cc11cb0415> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x31cad000 - 0x31d05fff  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31d06000 - 0x31d12fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x31d19000 - 0x31d1ffff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x31d20000 - 0x31d24fff  IOSurface armv7  <6ae77a40f8e93f28bc466ca93f5675d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x31d3b000 - 0x31d5efff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x31e2c000 - 0x31e30fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x31e43000 - 0x31e50fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x32039000 - 0x32045fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x32092000 - 0x320a3fff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x320b6000 - 0x320b9fff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x320ba000 - 0x3255cfff  UIKit armv7  <d72bcc68e76a3a55a963590cdcffe8cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x32566000 - 0x3270cfff  CoreData armv7  <b0215b6d4d143859a2b313ecade095ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x32789000 - 0x329b6fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <ec9bc89489763c6c93f86c5c490b2d69> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x32d56000 - 0x32d5afff  CertUI armv7  <f503892ef60e36108d28d8f9d6144d2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x32d81000 - 0x32d90fff  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x32d91000 - 0x32d9bfff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x32da8000 - 0x32e0cfff  MessageUI armv7  <b74d79ea691a35ada276f063b7217a20> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x3362b000 - 0x3366afff  QuickLook armv7  <802b1092542a3017a0380632502610d4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x3366b000 - 0x3366ffff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x33676000 - 0x33746fff  WebKit armv7  <6ff2796c2f933050ac6ecdee9fc6a216> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x33822000 - 0x3386efff  CoreTelephony armv7  <e8eb52ca5fe33c7488a33efd222e7804> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x33890000 - 0x338d8fff  CoreMedia armv7  <eb1f503312be3c93b07b2d0d25177000> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x3397d000 - 0x33a6bfff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x33a6c000 - 0x33b43fff  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x33c7c000 - 0x33cb8fff  IMFoundation armv7  <77bb4365a65b32a49523b03da0340dbc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x33cb9000 - 0x33ddefff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x33e4e000 - 0x33e77fff  AppleAccount armv7  <2ba44023410231fcb3f72f762ea3ce6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x33e91000 - 0x33e9dfff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x34005000 - 0x3401bfff  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x343b0000 - 0x34671fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34672000 - 0x34688fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x346aa000 - 0x346fbfff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x346fc000 - 0x34733fff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x3474d000 - 0x3477dfff  ContentIndex armv7  <7a64670bb2ff3ee39ddee1dc1c72f92d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x3483d000 - 0x34842fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x3491d000 - 0x34923fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x34a1c000 - 0x34a66fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <5e0a131bbfec305ea01f9e01f486da63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x34a67000 - 0x34a93fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <3aacc5b650e037c086a8ff6657d154bf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x34a94000 - 0x34a9dfff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x34bd6000 - 0x34bedfff  WebBookmarks armv7  <bd20a05587783a8e9596eef1d3615ea7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x34bee000 - 0x34c06fff  Notes armv7  <724966ed5cd4395cb70f9c996b123f53> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x34c99000 - 0x34cadfff  PersistentConnection armv7  <65682d21486836a3aa3e17b9461e7b3a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x34cb8000 - 0x34cedfff  DataAccess armv7  <89fd0c22338b37538cf61803a0bca9e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x34cf1000 - 0x34d6afff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x34e78000 - 0x34e7bfff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x34e82000 - 0x34e98fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <7ac5560851ce3cb3981068092074b409> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x34fe6000 - 0x350fdfff  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x35281000 - 0x352c6fff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x35412000 - 0x35447fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x35448000 - 0x35591fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x35599000 - 0x355e2fff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x358e8000 - 0x358eefff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x358ef000 - 0x35aacfff  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x35ad7000 - 0x35ad9fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x35b3e000 - 0x35b61fff  MobileSync armv7  <e42604c550283f4aa517ae8f108b340f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x35baf000 - 0x35bfdfff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x35c07000 - 0x35cb5fff  Message armv7  <b8221d43401d315fb84398b7aa570fc1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x35dba000 - 0x35dbdfff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x35f76000 - 0x3615afff  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x3615b000 - 0x3615bfff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x36299000 - 0x3629ffff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x362d4000 - 0x362e3fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <70ac33720f513f0f97ea2279260678ca> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x362e4000 - 0x362ecfff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x362ed000 - 0x362f7fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <e21a6e61bdd136b6805a9e3abe2e3d1f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x362f8000 - 0x362fffff  MailServices armv7  <ab2388ce733e38b7a261273a401bbbf1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x3630d000 - 0x36323fff  EAP8021X armv7  <fffe86a22bc434a6ae84f23bfecef9d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x3632a000 - 0x363ecfff  Celestial armv7  <2a59586b0ae937c3b25fe526924aa885> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x364b7000 - 0x364bbfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x364bd000 - 0x36583fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x36584000 - 0x36584fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x3659f000 - 0x365a2fff  ActorKit armv7  <434c756a6b053f4ba3c954cfccddbf59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x36631000 - 0x36636fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <2bb524b3bb3c3eb2932ce13b655b7c7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x36738000 - 0x36758fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x368bc000 - 0x368d9fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x368da000 - 0x368e9fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <ca5b10014b473d2eaec5c48d89ee1b54> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x3692a000 - 0x3692afff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x36a58000 - 0x36a59fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7850befd26b630f183ee326aaadd7b34> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x36b47000 - 0x36b4afff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x36b84000 - 0x36c75fff  QuartzCore armv7  <a2afbe6483683d05ad51b106f98776e2> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x36cfa000 - 0x36cfbfff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <66e985f3eea03ef08afb7cf4c153f76e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x36d3d000 - 0x36d41fff  FTClientServices armv7  <21de970d7ebb3e7fb502a0a5451b0806> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x36d42000 - 0x36dcefff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x36dcf000 - 0x3758dfff  WebCore armv7  <814351ff217e3425a8e532c2e2251f73> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x3795b000 - 0x3795ffff  Marco armv7  <8dea3e558fe534ff868fc92e215ce53b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x3799c000 - 0x37a46fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x37a5d000 - 0x37aa0fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x37acb000 - 0x37b78fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x37bb8000 - 0x37bc0fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x37bc3000 - 0x37bc8fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x37c6c000 - 0x37cb0fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x37d27000 - 0x37d8afff  IMCore armv7  <6e26e99b9b5f3829a8486ffd8c64f0d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x37da5000 - 0x37e3efff  EventKit armv7  <d67aa1508ee7306b8e2a45c76ffddff0> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x37eff000 - 0x37f01fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x37f1c000 - 0x37f1ffff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
```

Answer (score 6):

So, in general, performing heavy lifting on the main thread will cause the UI of the app to lock up. The OS is looking for applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions to return after a reasonable amount of time. If it doesn't, it'll kill your app and give you the 8badf00d exception code. Just look at your elapsed time; more than 20 seconds! I've gotten 8badf00d for launches taking less than 5 seconds.

And obviously you won't get this crash on all devices all the time. If your set up depends on internet connectivity (as mine did), you may get it on a device that is trying to connect on Edge or a shady WiFi connection. If you're doing a ton of heavy graphics stuff, this could pass the loading time threshold, as well. It's possible that the only reason you're seeing this in iOS5 is that Apple reduced the loading time maximum limit for iOS5 devices (better hardware, better software, load times should be better as well, one could make the argument). I would highly suggest kicking off the set up in a background thread. If that setup is integral to your application, consider loading up your splash screen first with a loading indicator, and removing that view once the set up is complete. From a user perspective, they would just see the splash screen on launch like normal, and then maybe an activity indicator or something appear, and then when it disappears they have a fully configured set up.

The other options would be to optimize the heck out of your loading code so that it happens in less than a few seconds. But if you're at 20 seconds now, I don't see THAT much optimization being possible.

***UPDATE:*** From the apple docs:

> The most common cause for watchdog timeout crashes in a network
>   application is synchronous networking on the main thread. There are
>   four contributing factors here:
>   synchronous networking — This is where you make a network request and block waiting for the response.
>   main thread — Synchronous networking is less than ideal in general, but it causes specific problems if you do it on the main
>   thread. Remember that the main thread is responsible for running the
>   user interface. If you block the main thread for any significant
>   amount of time, the user interface becomes unacceptably unresponsive.
>   long timeouts — If the network just goes away (for example, the user is on a train which > goes into a tunnel), any pending network
>   request won't fail until some timeout has expired. Most network
>   timeouts are measured in minutes, meaning that a blocked synchronous
>   network request on the main thread can keep the user interface
>   unresponsive for minutes at a time.
>   Trying to avoid this problem by reducing the network timeout is not a good idea. In some > situations it can take many seconds for a
>   network request to succeed, and if you always time out early then
>   you'll never make any progress at all.
>   watchdog — In order to keep the user interface responsive, iOS includes a watchdog mechanism. If your application fails to respond to
>   certain user interface events (launch, suspend, resume, terminate) in
>   time, the watchdog will kill your application and generate a watchdog
>   timeout crash report. The amount of time the watchdog gives you is not
>   formally documented, but it's always less than a network timeout.
>   One tricky aspect of this problem is that it's highly dependent on the
>   network environment. If you always test your application in your
>   office, where network connectivity is good, you'll never see this type
>   of crash. However, once you start deploying your application to end
>   users—who will run it in all sorts of network environments—crashes
>   like this will become common.
>   Warning To summarize, if you make synchronous networking calls on the
>   main thread, your application will suffer from watchdog timeout
>   crashes when it's deployed to a wide range of users.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Actually the app launches within 1-2 seconds, and works fine for 99% of our users (who number in the hundreds of thousands). The real question is: why is our app taking 20 seconds to launch on these rare occasions that it crashes? All of the startup code is handed off immediately and there's no reason for startup to be taking so long. The crash log doesn't seem to point to any of our code.

Comment: [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadGame) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; does not hand it off. It performs this on the main thread.

Comment: It does allow applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions to return immediately.

Comment: I appreciate that, however in this case I think it's a red herring. I understand that SOMETHING is overloading the main thread, but it's not the "loadGame" procedure that's kicked off in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions. The proof of this is that we can put an infinite loop in the "loadGame" procedure and it will neither crash the app nor cause a watchdog timeout. It will only cause the app to freeze. We've used this design pattern across many of our apps and has been rock solid for us. So the question is, how can we figure out what the real culprit is in causing the watchdog timeout?

Comment: Symbolic sting your crash report will give you better debug info, including the line in your code.

Comment: I thought this was a symbolicated crash report. It has been imported into Organizer. Is there something else we need to do?

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, `0x8badf00d` means something is making the app take too long to launch.

It looks like the users who are having this problem have too much stuff stored in their preferences (`NSUserDefaults`). You shouldn't use `NSUserDefaults` to store more than a few settings. You definitely shouldn't be storing large images or blobs of binary data in there!

The crash log shows that it's taking a really really long time to read and parse the file that the preferences for the app are stored in. Usually this is because the file is too big. The preferences for your app are read in the first time anything checks, `+[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`, which some iOS code is doing at startup. (Probably to check language preferences, or for a debugging flag — but the exact reason isn't that important, you would still hit the same behavior the first time you used `NSUserDefaults`.)

To save data that's large enough to cause an `0x8badf00d`, [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/) is probably a better API to use.

Answer (score 0):

We just isolated a similar startup crash to the call to Apple's server to check for in-app purchases. By removing all in-app purchases from sale, the app started running again for the users who reported issues. Hope that helps!