# IPhone Crash Logs - What is the elapsed CPU time

Tags: ios, iphone

In iPhone Crash logs, i see the following information.

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
iOSMyApp[2687] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
     identifier: Suspending process: iOSMyApp[2687] permittedBackgroundDuration: 10.000000 reason: suspend owner pid:15 
preventSuspend  preventThrottleDownCPU  preventThrottleDownUI 
)}

**Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 10.060 (user 10.060, system 0.000), 100% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 7.785, 77% CPU**

I Understand that Elapsed application CPU time includes the total CPU time utilized by the application including the waiting time for device resources.

**But What is this 7.785 seconds ?**

Is this the time taken to render the Screen UI ? or 
Is this the time taken to return from applicationDidFinishWithLaunchingOptions Method ?

I get this doubt because Application launch time till 20 seconds (approx because no fixed metric is defined by apple) is accepted by apple. But then for 7.785 seconds why did we get the crash log ?

Please help me understand this value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908882/application-failed-to-launch-in-time

Comment: So, is this 7.785 seconds = Time taken by didFinishLaunching method ?

Comment: Are you by any chance calling beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: without calling a corresponding endBackgroundTask:?

Comment: I dont have access to the source code ... I am testing the application using the .app and .dysm file. But again, my question is not why the application crashed. It is what is the time mentioned in Elapsed application CPU time (seconds).

Comment: As per my guessing your application want to execute extra time for execution.

Comment: for more information read http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:

Comment: http://www.techdoubts.com/what-is-cpu-time-and-elapsed-time/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Time mentioned is the time taken to return from applicationDidFinishWithLaunchingOptions method.

Referred to these links and got this information.

[App Crashes on Startup with iOS 5 - Cannot Reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036531/app-crashes-on-startup-with-ios-5-cannot-reproduce)
[iPhone 4 vs iPhone 5 TestFlight issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779475/iphone-4-vs-iphone-5-testflight-issue)
[Unable to start debug IPA on iOS 6, it runs perfectly on iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970671/unable-to-start-debug-ipa-on-ios-6-it-runs-perfectly-on-ios-5)